# Angular Dropdown Menu display multiple things

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am creating an angular application and I am having trouble displaying what the user is selecting in the drop down menu. So for example, a user chooses the state of Texas, now they get all the information from the state of texas, i want to display the period, region_code, region and so forth...

```
<div>
    <select [(ngModel)]="stateSelected" style="margin: auto; width: 50%; border: 2px;" name="" id="">
    <option *ngFor="let state of users$" [value]="state.region_code">
      <span>{{ state.region }}</span>
    </option>
  </select>
    <br /> selected value is {{ stateSelected }}
</div>
```

This is the Typescript below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../HealthIT.model';
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-state',
  templateUrl: './select-state.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-state.component.css'],
})
export class SelectStateComponent implements OnInit {
  users$: User[];
  stateSelected: string;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.stateSelected = 'TX';

    return this.dataService
      .getUsers()
      .subscribe((data) => (this.users$ = data));
  }
}
```

data from api:

```
   {
      "region":"Texas",
      "region_code":"TX",
      "period":"2015",
      "atleast_one_measure":"",
      "immunization_measure":"0.98",
      "reportable_lab_results_measure":"0.81",
      "syndromic_surveillance_measure":"0.59",
      "registry_measure":"0.04",
      "stage_2_hospitals_all_measures":"",
      "stage_1_hospitals_all_measures":""
   },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `value` attribute, you can use the angular [`ngValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor) directive which gives you more control over the value you want to store. With the `value` attribute you can only store a string, with the `ngValue`, you can store/reference an object. Try this:

Typescript

```
export class SelectStateComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  stateSelected: State; // <-- What ever your the state type is.
  ...
}
```

Template

```
<div>
    <select [(ngModel)]="stateSelected" style="margin: auto; width: 50%; border: 2px;" name="" id="">
    <option *ngFor="let state of users$" [ngValue]="state">
      <span>{{ state.region }}</span>
    </option>
  </select>
    <br /> selected value is {{ stateSelected.region_code }}
</div>
```

Comment: That gives me a [Object Object ] answer

Comment: That is because `stateSelected` is now an object, you can now access which ever property you like. Checkout my template code, I'm now accessing the `region_code` property rather than `stateSelected` directly.